# jQuery events not firing after "cleaning" Knockout bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, knockout.js

In my project, I have an `<div>` where I specifically apply my Knockout.js bindings. I have to instantiate different viewmodels in that area depending on what the user clicks.

To prevent getting a *cannot call bindings twice on the same element* error, I first have to "Clean" the bindings to make the area available again. I call the initial `applyBindings()` function:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"), document.getElementById("bindings-area"));
```

Eventually, I will clean the `<div>` and call the new bindings:

```
var element = $("#bindings-area")[0];
ko.cleanNode(element);
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("NEW", "Bindings"), document.getElementById("bindings-area"));
```

**Problem:** When I include an HTML button in the `#bindings-area` div, it will no longer work after I clean the bindings and instantiate the new model. I'm sure it has to do with the `ko.cleanNode()` function somehow removing the *button* bindings as well. How can I re-initiate them or prevent `cleanNode()` from operating on the button in the first place?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jL6L01xs/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is nicely described in [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html#overriding-the-clean-up-of-external-data). This quote describes what the issue is and what needs to be done:

> When removing an element, Knockout runs logic to clean up any data
>   associated with the element. As part of this logic, Knockout calls
>   jQuery’s `cleanData` method if jQuery is loaded in your page. In
>   advanced scenarios, you may want to prevent or customize how this data
>   is removed in your application. Knockout exposes a function,
>   `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.cleanExternalData(node)`, that can be
>   overridden to support custom logic. For example, to prevent `cleanData`
>   from being called, an empty function could be used to replace the
>   standard `cleanExternalData` implementation:
>
> ```
> ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.cleanExternalData = function () {
>     // Do nothing. Now any jQuery data associated with elements will
>     // not be cleaned up when the elements are removed from the DOM.
> };
> ```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL6L01xs/3/).