# Knockout "with" binding removes my jquery DOM events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, knockout.js

I have several jquery dom events that are created on DOM load or document ready. These are mostly default behaviors that should be applied to all forms in my application. Example:

```
$('input:text').focus(function ()
{
    $(this).select();
});
```

Right before applying knockout binding, I can check my dom elements and all events are there:

[image: before knockout binding]

But when I run the applyBindings method to bind the viewmodel to my DOM, the ["with" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) removes all events that are not related to knockout:

[image: after knockout biding]

I have tried overwriting the **cleanExternalData** as explained on the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html#overriding-the-clean-up-of-external-data) and on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31009412/1715160). But that did not help with this, the function is replaced, but the events are still removed from the DOM when the templating is applied on the binding process.

For the record, this is not an exclusive behavior of the *with* function, but all anonymous templating functions also do that, foreach, if, ifnot. Using *template*, as expected, also behaves the same way. The DOM element is completely destroyed, stored as a template, then added again on my document when the condition is satisfied, but now without any jquery event handlers.

How to avoid that knockout removes the events from my DOM elements?

Comment: The only real answer is one you probably don't want to hear: if you use knockout, you'll have to use it for all DOM related features. I.e.: you use the `hasFocus` binding and only apply event listeners in *custom bindings*, never in other parts of the code.

Comment: @user3297291 that is not really an answer, as other parts of my knockout code are not affected, like foreach-bound elements. Not only that, but jquery events created *after* the binding also work. The problem lies in bindings that use knockout templating (if, ifnot, with), that will destroy the DOM and create it again when necessary.

Comment: Are you unable to move applyBindings in front of your jquery event initializations?

Comment: The events are in a more generic level on the application, while the knockout code is in a more specific level.

Comment: "other parts of my knockout code are not affected" You should consider all parts that are inside a knockout binding context to be "lost". You have no guarantee knockout will respect any attached (jQuery) binding handlers. Your `foreach` might work now, but break in the future. Why can't you use the `event` binding instead? Or, vice versa, why not use *only* jQuery and include some templating plugin?

Comment: *foreach* works because it doesn't destroy the dom element, unlike *if*, *ifnot* and *with*. I require this binding because there is no other function that will bind an object to the DOM and allow me to use properties of that object on my inputs.

Comment: Have you tried not using the "with" binding? As you said the binding alters the DOM, and if a dom element is removed and re-added it's not really the same element anymore and won't have any of the previous element's events. There's not much way around that. You can either re-attach the events in a subscription to the target, or you can drill down into the target on every other binding and avoid the "with" to begin with.

Comment: *with* and *foreach* are the only way to bind an observable object to dom elements. That way, whenever a property of the object is changed, the dom is updated to reflect that change.

Comment: Which version of Knockout are you using?

Comment: @MichaelBest 3.4.2

Comment: I made an attempt at using *foreach* using a fake array, the result was the same. Sample code: *foreach: { data: [observableObject], as: 'objectAlias' }*

Comment: Of course. foreach modifies the DOM same as If/With/NotIf. That's kind of the point of using knockout.

Comment: *modify* the DOM, yes. But *destroy* the DOM and remove data unrelated to knockout..? Now, I dont think that's the point. And my question is requesting help to figure out the issue or what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: KO is in charge of the DOM - you have to work with it.  Use an event binding, or write your own binding handler.  The `with` binding effectively applies the inner HTML as a template with a given object as $data.  As noted earlier, templates are stamped in as new nodes.  Technically you could try to have a with: binding not do this, but that would open up so many cans of worms - event handlers and bindings referencing potentially no-longer-valid observables, etc.
Work within KO - use binding handlers, etc.  You'd have the same needs with Angular, React, etc.

Comment: @IanYates Apparently, this behavior I am experiencing is not expected at all, as my initial object is never falsy. It should only destroy the DOM if the object is falsy. There will be a new binding, **using**, on 3.5 that will not remove the dom, according to [this](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1811). I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is how I fixed my problem and I hope this can clarify things to others that don't want to destroy their DOM as well. If you don't want that knockout to destroy your DOM, that is possible since version 2.2. And thus, destroying the DOM when that is not necessary is not *intended* behavior and can be avoided.

I had tried several bidings created by [Michael Best](https://github.com/mbest) before, like his [using binding that will come in knockout 3.5](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1811), and let or withLight (which became *using* now). None really worked. These simplified bidings would load the initial object, but not update the dom when this object properties had changed.

But this helped me to figure out what I am doing wrong. When I wanted to update my observable object, I was using **myViewModel.observableObject(NewObject)**, like the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables) told me to do:

> To write a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass the new value as a parameter. For example, calling **myViewModel.personName('Mary')** will change the name value to 'Mary'.

But I wasn't passing a single property's value, I was passing a new object that had the same structure (same properties). And this triggered knockout that the old object was destroyed (and thus, **falsy** for a second) and a new object took its place, even though all properties are there, they just got different values. Unlike the documentation told me, it didn't simply *changed the value*, but changed the entire object.

To go around this, instead of doing that, First, I had to initiate my viewModel with this object already created, using dummy data, this makes knockout not destroy the DOM when *applyBindings* is called. Then, when I want my object to update, I replaced the value of each property of the observable object to have the value of the new object. This didn't destroy the object and knockout updated my binding properly.

```
myViewModel.setSelectedItem = function setSelectedItem (newObject)
{
    for (var prop in myViewModel.myObservableObject())
        myViewModel.myObservableObject()[prop](newObject[prop]);
}
```

The **with** binding still killed some of my events (my angular ng-change for one of my components, for instance), but it kept all jquery events in there (which is great). And the [using](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/f07616a67df0ef9b6e7b289699e706a2ab9891fe/src/binding/defaultBindings/using.js) binding didn't kill any of my events at all (which is even better).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding elements to a specific node, you can use a databinding to use the jquery on() functionality to handle events.  Here's a binding I use:

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
ko.bindingHandlers.eventListener = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var params = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (!(params instanceof Array)) {
            params = [params];
        }
        params.forEach(function (param) {
            $(element).on(param.event, param.selector, function (event) {
                param.callback(ko.dataFor(this), ko.contextFor(this), event);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

});

Usage:

```
<div data-bind="eventListener: [
             { event: 'click', selector: '.copyInclusionRule', callback: copyInclusionRule},
             { event: 'click', selector: '.deleteInclusionRule', callback: deleteInclusionRule}]">
 ... other knockout template stuff here ...
</div>
```

The above will listen for click events on either an element with the specified class and perform the callback when the event is received for anything within the div's 'scope'.  The value of 'event' param can be anything that on() uses.

I think the reason why you can't leverage the cleanNode overrides is that your dom is being completely destroyed and re-created..at least that's my theory, if there was a way to get some kind of memory ID of the pre-applyBindings() dom elements and then after the applyBindings is called, are those new nodes? If they are new nodes, it's not something you can't fix with cleaning, those nodes are gone.

Comment: to answer your question. The images on my question are exactly *before* and *after* applyBindings was called.

Comment: right, I can't quite tell if the element hovered is the same element as the one that exists after applyBinding().  Maybe in your console, store a global var to the element reference, then run apply bindings, find the element again, and then do a console.log(oldElement === newElement).  If it's a new element, I don't think this is a cleaning problem.  I think you should look into 'unobtrusive event handling from here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Comment: I can confirm it is no longer the same object. I did a jquery select, saved it on a var and compared to the object after *applyBindings*. The return was false. However, I already expected that. When **with** is used, the DOM element is removed from the document, becomes an anonymous template, then is inserted back again when the condition is met.